# Merge multiple `$lookup` into one

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb, express

I am using same collection in multiple lookups but with different local key, here is my
sample collection

```js
db={
  "category": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "name": "asia",
      "slug": "asia",
      "level": 1
    },
    {
      "_id": 2,
      "name": "India",
      "slug": "india",
      "level": 2
    },
    {
      "_id": 3,
      "name": "State",
      "slug": "state",
      "level": 3
    },
    {
      "_id": 4,
      "name": "City",
      "slug": "city",
      "level": 4
    },
  ],
  "story": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "title": "This Sample Title",
      "slug": "this-sample-title",
      "category_id": 1,
      "sub_category_id": 2,
      "l3_sub_category_id": 3,
      "l4_sub_category_id": 4,
    },
  ]
}
```

and using this aggregate query, to fetch data from collection.

```js
db.story.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "category",
      "localField": "category_id",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "category_data"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "category",
      "localField": "sub_category_id",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "sub_category_data"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "category",
      "localField": "l3_sub_category_id",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "l3_sub_category_data"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "category",
      "localField": "l4_sub_category_id",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "l4_sub_category_data"
    }
  }
])
```

and this is my output, that i am getting from my query

```json
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "category_data": [
      {
        "_id": 1,
        "level": 1,
        "name": "asia",
        "slug": "asia"
      }
    ],
    "category_id": 1,
    "l3_sub_category_data": [
      {
        "_id": 3,
        "level": 3,
        "name": "State",
        "slug": "state"
      }
    ],
    "l3_sub_category_id": 3,
    "l4_sub_category_data": [
      {
        "_id": 4,
        "level": 4,
        "name": "City",
        "slug": "city"
      }
    ],
    "l4_sub_category_id": 4,
    "slug": "this-sample-title",
    "sub_category_data": [
      {
        "_id": 2,
        "level": 2,
        "name": "India",
        "slug": "india"
      }
    ],
    "sub_category_id": 2,
    "title": "This Sample Title"
  }
]
```

can anybody help me how can I merge these multiple lookups on same collection, into single lookup.
Playground : https://mongoplayground.net/p/XNvG1hBROsj

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: If you want identical output with a single `"$lookup"`, here's a [mongoplayground.net example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hIKQiaZ7Dr8) that isn't particularly efficient.